# Git add -p not applying edit

Tags: git

I'm trying to use git add -p to add a particular part of a file to the staging area,
I run the command "git add -p $file", when I get to the hunk I want I'm presented with this:

```
@@ -24,9 +28,16 @@ void *sdlStore(void *data,int option)
            case SET_FRAMETIME:frameTime = *(Uint32 *)data;break;
            case GET_FRAMETIME:return &frameTime;break;
            case SET_BACKGROUND: background = (bgData *)data;break;
-           case GET_BACKGROUND: return &background;break;
-           default:break;
+           case GET_BACKGROUND: return (void *)background;break;
+           case SET_BG_SIZE: bgSizes = (int *)data;break;
+           case GET_BG_SIZE: return (void *)bgSizes;break;
+           default: puts("DEBUG: sdlStore() 1"); return (void *)1;break;
        }
    }
+   else
+   {
+       puts("DEBUG: sdlStore() 2");
+       return (void *)1;
+   }
    return 0;
 }
```

What I want to add and only add is:

```
+           case GET_BACKGROUND: return (void *)background;break;
+           case SET_BG_SIZE: bgSizes = (int *)data;break;
+           case GET_BG_SIZE: return (void *)bgSizes;break;
```

The "default:break" should be at the bottom of the switch statement as it is in the file itself, whenever I try to edit the hunk to my liking it doesn't apply, only displaying an error.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to edit the hunk with `e` so it looks like:

```
@@ -24,9 +28,16 @@ void *sdlStore(void *data,int option)
            case SET_FRAMETIME:frameTime = *(Uint32 *)data;break;
            case GET_FRAMETIME:return &frameTime;break;
            case SET_BACKGROUND: background = (bgData *)data;break;
-           case GET_BACKGROUND: return &background;break;
+           case GET_BACKGROUND: return (void *)background;break;
+           case SET_BG_SIZE: bgSizes = (int *)data;break;
+           case GET_BG_SIZE: return (void *)bgSizes;break;
            default:break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

You have to keep that one `-` line in there because you're *changing* the `GET_BACKGROUND` line. Also, I replaced the `-` at the start of the `default` line with a space because you don't want to change that line at all.